# Why this operation is not following the precedence and associativity table in C?

Tags: c, operator-precedence, associativity

I was trying to learn about difference between functions and macro with arguments (aka 'macro function' ?) and i got this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define mult_m(a) a*a 

int mult_f(int a){
    return a*a;
}

int main()
{
    int x=3,y=3,z=3;
    //printf("%d\n",mult_m(x++));
    //printf("%d\n",mult_f(++y));
    printf("%d\n",++z * z++);
    printf("%d\n",z);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is: 20

I know about precedence and associativity and this ouput does not make sense to me, in my headcannon this should be:

- Postfix increment have higher precedence than * or prefix ++ so:
  ++z * 3++ ---> ++z * 3 (z now is equal to 4) ---> ++4 * 3
- The * and prefix ++ have same precedence so the associativity is right to left so:
  ++4 * 3 ---> 5*3=15

HEADCANNON OUPUT: 15

ACTUAL OUTPUT: 20

Can you explain me why this is happening? if you have a C standard reference to explain this i would really appreciate it

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "The output is: 20" no, it is not. You print two numbers, not one. Please always be correct and precise with describing what happens. Don't just pick a random Part.

Answer (score 3):

> Can you explain me why this is happening?

Yes, because it invokes undefined behaviour as you have unsequenced modifications of the variable `z`.

If you enable warnings the compiler will warn you about it

```
<source>:23:19: warning: operation on 'z' may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
```

This is one of the reasons why macros can be very dangerous. Your square macro if used with post or pre increment operator will invoke UB too.